# C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to get a word from a text input based on a index. Here the word should be in flowe brackets.

I will try to explain by giving an example.
If my input is `hh{jhh}jkhjh{jkjhh{kljk}j}adajskjj}`. For any character index, if it lies in between a pair of brackets I have to fetch that word including brackets.
In the above input if index is 2 or 4 output should be `{jhh}`.

Comment: What should happen if the index is 14?

Comment: Your brackets don't seem to be opened and closed properly, is this intentional?

Comment: If the index is 14, as there is no associated closed bracket is not existing it will return nothing.

Comment: Brackets are intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There's a number of problems, of course. First, you didn't say how you want to handle nested brackets. If you need to handle nested brackets, you're out of luck with a simple regular expression, because you need a context-free grammar for that. Also note that the following implementation is naive in that it has linear time complexity on a word lookup (time to lookup a word is directly proportional to the number of matches found). That would only be a problem for large number of matches, however. Better implementation could use, for instance, a sorted array of matches and binary search for lookup.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ParsedInput
    {
        public static readonly Regex RegularExpression = new Regex("{[a-z]*}");

        private MatchCollection matches;

        public ParsedInput(string input)
        {
            matches = RegularExpression.Matches(input);
        }

        public bool TryGetWord(int index, out string word)
        {
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                if (index >= match.Index && index < (match.Index + match.Length))
                {
                    word = match.Captures[0].Value;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            word = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

To use, do:

```
var parsed = new ParsedInput(input);
string word = "";

if (parsed.TryGetWord(index, out word))
{
    // A word exists at the given index, do something.
}
else
{
    // Handle missing word at the given index (optional).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking for, regexp is regexp you can't tell it to start looking from index i and also move search backwards.

Regexp you're looking is probably something like this:

```
(\{.*\})
```

If you're looking for a way to get just those groups where start > index < end I would probably capture all groups and then iterate through them to check whether index is between start and end.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best **not** to use regular expressions for this because it is very specific and the pattern is not generic enough (missing brackets e.g.)

Write your own tokenizer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your specs were pretty brief, but something like this is probably going to be better than a 
Regex.

```
string GetWord(string value, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= value.Length)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
    int start = (value[index] == '}') ? index-1 : index;
    int end = (value[index] == '}') ? index : index+1;
    int count = 1;
    for (; start >= 0 && count > 0; start--)
    {
        count += (value[start] == '}') ? 1 : 0;
        count -= (value[start] == '{') ? 1 : 0;
    }
    for (count = 1; end < value.Length && count > 0; end++)
    {
        count += (value[end] == '{') ? 1 : 0;
        count -= (value[end] == '}') ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return value.Substring(++start, end - start);
}
```

Output for your test string would be:

```
GetWord(input,2) == "{jhh}"
GetWord(input,8) == "hh{jhh}jkhjh{jkjhh{kljk}j}adajskjj}"
GetWord(input,14) == "{jkjhh{kljk}j}"
GetWord(input,30) == "hh{jhh}jkhjh{jkjhh{kljk}j}adajskjj}"
GetWord(input,99) == ""
```